# Average of a random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with probability density function $f(x) =2xe^{-x^2}$. Let $Y = X^2$.
>
> 1) Compute $E(Y)$ without obtaining the probability density function of $Y$.
>
> 2) Compute probability density function of $Y$ and then compute $E(Y)$.

Here's my resolution:

1) $F_X{(x)} = \int_{-\infty}^x 2xe^{-x^2} dx = -e^{x^2}|_{-\infty}^x = -e^{-x^2}$

So, $F_Y{(y)} = P(Y \leq y) = P(X^2 \leq y) = P(X \leq \sqrt{y}) = F_X{(\sqrt{y})} = -e^{-\sqrt{y}^2} = -e^{-y}, y\geq 0$

Then, $f_Y{(y)} = \frac{dF_Y{(y)}}{dy} = e^{-y}$

2) $f_Y{(y)} = 2\sqrt{y}e^{-y^2}|\frac{d(\sqrt{y})}{dy}| = 2\sqrt{y}e^{-\sqrt{y}^2}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} = e^{-\sqrt{y}^2}$ $= e^{-y}, y \geq 0$

It happens that my professor said that my solution had a mistake, but I can't find it. Can someone help me, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is $f$ defined? That would point out one mistake. And did you answer the questions actually asked?

Comment: f(x) = 2xe^(-x^2)

Comment: For what $x$? You should add that as you have added for $f_Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the proposed probability density function $f$ takes negative values, which is forbidden. Actually, I guess that the true density is $f(x) = 2xe^{-x^2}\Bbb I_{x>0}$, where $\Bbb I$ denotes the indicator function. Thus, $X$ must be a *positive* random variable. Then, you obviously didn't answer the question.

1) Let's perform the direct computation $$
E(Y) = E(X^2) = \int_{\Bbb R} x^2 f(x)\,\text d x = 1
$$

2) The [change of variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function) $y=x^2$ from $\Bbb R_+$ to itself is one to one, and the pdf of $Y$ satisfies $$
f_Y(y) = \frac{f(\sqrt{y})}{2\sqrt{y}} = e^{-y}\,\Bbb I_{y>0} \, .
$$
Therefore, $Y$ has exponential distribution $\text{Exp}(1)$, which expected value is $E(Y) = 1$.

Comment: Are both  line 1) (of yours and mine) correct? Because from my one, we can say that Y follows Exp(1), so E(Y) = 1

Comment: @Anonymous If the problem asks explicitly to compute *$E(Y)$ without obtaining the probability density function of $Y$*, then a direct calculation is expected. In particular, you should not determine the distribution of $Y$ in 1), but do so in 2).

Comment: @EditPiaAf got it, thanks.